# i need to change all my user databases from full recovery to simple by using command in four servers

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to change all my user databases from full recovery to simple recovery by using command in all my servers. need to create a stored procedure can you please give me a solution .. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey and welcome to DBA.SE. Could you specify the RDBMS in the question, such as sql server, oracle, mysql,... and add it to the tags.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are talking about changing this on a SQL Server instance**

One way to do this for one instance is scripting the statements out and executing them yourself after validating.

```
SELECT 'ALTER DATABASE '+QUOTENAME(name)+' SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;' 
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE state_desc = 'ONLINE' 
AND database_id > 4
AND recovery_model_desc != 'SIMPLE';
```

**A simple procedure to change the states without manual intervention**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ChangeRecoveryModelUserDatabases
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

DECLARE @CMD nvarchar(max),@DatabaseName varchar(500)
DECLARE C CURSOR FOR SELECT name  FROM sys.databases WHERE state_desc = 'ONLINE' AND database_id > 4AND recovery_model_desc != 'SIMPLE';

OPEN C
FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @DatabaseName;


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET @CMD =  'ALTER DATABASE '+QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName)+' SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;'

    PRINT @CMD;
    --EXEC (@CMD);


FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @DatabaseName
END
CLOSE C
DEALLOCATE C

END
```

*Don't forget to uncomment the `EXEC()` if you want to execute it directly.*

Comment: Thank u so much..

Comment: @pavankumar no problem! If the answer solved your question, feel free to [mark it as solved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)